# Rewriting the series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{s=0}^{\infty} h(k) g(s) z^{-(k+s)}$ in terms of $l = k + s$ and $k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

In one of the text book I found the following expression

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{s=0}^{\infty} h(k) g(s) z^{-(k+s)}$$

Letting $k+s=l$, then the book has written the following

> $$\sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{l} h(k) g(l-k) z^{-l}.$$

Whereas I am getting

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{l=k}^{\infty} h(k) g(l-k) z^{-l}.$$

Can somebody help me in simplifying the summation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are the same expression.

Note that in the first expression, $l$ is fixed in the first place, then $k$ runs from $0$ to $l$ because $k+s=l$ and $s\in \mathbb{N}$.

In your expression, you fix $k$ first and changes $l$, which is the same.

You can write out a few terms of possible combinations of $k$ and $l$ for each expression and compare them.